# Django : How to use LIKE while fetching data from mysql DB

Tags: python, mysql, django

I need a way to fetch similar records from DB using LIKE from Django .
My code is :

```
def fetchProductsDate1(request):
    query = request.session.get('query')
    date1 = request.session.get('date1')
    db = pymysql.connect(host=host,user=user,passwd=passwd,db=dbName)
    # Create a Cursor object to execute queries.
    cur = db.cursor()
    # Select data from table using SQL query.
    stmt = "SELECT FSN FROM tab WHERE query LIKE '%s' AND DATE(updated_at) LIKE '%s' " % (query.replace("'", r"\'"), date1)
    log.info(stmt)
    cur.execute(stmt)
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    json_data = rows[0][0]
```

The db statement looks like:

```
SELECT num FROM tab WHERE query LIKE 'soch sarees' AND DATE(updated_at) LIKE '2018-11-14'
```

I want the statement to be like :

```
SELECT num FROM tab WHERE query LIKE '%soch sarees%' AND DATE(updated_at) LIKE '2018-11-14'
```

Any help will be really nice :)

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't be using string formatting for inserting parameters; this is open to SQL injection.

Comment: `cur.execute("SELECT FSN FROM tab WHERE query LIKE '%s' AND DATE(updated_at) LIKE '%s'", ('%' + query.replace("'", r"\'") + '%', '%' + date1 + '%'))`. You may need to drop the quotation marks around `%s`, in the query string, not able to test.

Comment: I swear, the mysql library choosing `%s` rather than `?` is about as gun-to-foot as things can get. The misunderstanding writes itself; the `%s` in the context of a query string here is _not_ the same as a regular `%s` in string interpolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `%%` to do that

```
stmt = "SELECT FSN FROM tab WHERE query LIKE '%%%s%%' AND DATE(updated_at) LIKE '%s' " % (query.replace("'", r"\'"), date1)
```

Which will give us

> SELECT FSN FROM tab WHERE query LIKE '%soch sarees%' AND DATE(updated_at) LIKE '2018-11-14'

Also, I think it' a bad practice to concat parameters like this.This opens path to SQL Injection

You could try:

```
select_stmt = "SELECT FSN FROM tab WHERE query LIKE '%%%(name)%%%' AND DATE(updated_at) LIKE '%(date)%'"
cursor.execute(select_stmt, { 'name': 'soch sarees','date':'2018-11-14' })
```

Comment: No, please don't. This is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: stmt = "SELECT FSN FROM tab WHERE query LIKE '%%%s%%%' AND DATE(updated_at) LIKE '%s' " % (query.replace("'", r"\'"), date1)

Comment: Please see my comments under the question

Comment: @roganjosh yep. It is.